# Perl regex presumably removing non ASCII characters

Tags: perl, transliteration

I found a code with regex where it is claimed that it strips the text of any non-ASCII characters.
The code is written in Perl and the part of code that does it is:

```
$sentence =~ tr/\000-\011\013-\014\016-\037\041-\055\173-\377//d;
```

I want to understand how this regex works and in order to do this I have used [regexr](https://regexr.com/). I found out that `\000`, `\011`, `\013`, `\014`, `\016`, `\037`, `\041`, `\055`, `\173`, `\377` mean separate characters as NULL, TAB, VERTICAL TAB ... But I still do not get why "-" symbols are used in the regex. Do they really mean "dash symbol" as shown in [regexr](https://regexr.com/) or something else? Is this regex really suited for deleting non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a regex. The dash indicates a character range, like inside a regex character class `[a-z]`.

The expression deletes some ASCII characters, too (mainly whitespace) and spares a range of characters which are not ASCII; the full ASCII range would simply be `\000-\177`.

To be explicit, the `d` flag says to delete any characters not between the first pair of slashes. See further the [documentation.](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#tr%2f%2f%2f)

Comment: Why don't you consider the part between "tr/" and "//d" to be a regex?

Comment: @RaphaelP, Because it's not. [`tr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) doesn't take a [Perl regex pattern](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) or anything else that could be considered a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: See the documentation, or experimentally examine what `tr/.*//` does.

Comment: @RaphaelP `tr//` is the transliterate operator and doesn't have the same ruleset as the match `m//` or replace `s///`operators. The [Quote-Like Operators section of the perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) has more info.

Comment: Elucidation appreciated.